# Plot region formed by all points $\left\{(\cos(x+y),\cos(x-y))\mid(x,y)\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)^2\right\}$

Tags: plotting

How can I use Mathematica to plot the region
$$\left\{\big(\cos(x+y),\cos(x-y)\big)\left\lvert(x,y)\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)^2\right.\right\}~?$$

I thought of using `RegionPlot` and "$\arccos$"s, but this wouldn't work if I were to plot the region
$$\left\{\big(\cos\left(x^2+\sin y\right),\cos\left(\mathrm e^x-y\right)\big)\left\lvert(x,y)\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)^2\right.\right\}.$$
Another way might be to use two great loop with small increment of $x$, $y$, but that's not efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)` can plot region:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[x + y], Cos[x - y]}, {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Comment: @youthdoo glad was helpful. Enjoy time with Wolfram Language/Mathematica. :)

Answer (score 1):

Or use `ParametricRegion` + `Region`. (or `RegionPlot`)

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{Cos[x + y], 
    Cos[x - y]}, {{x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/2}}];
Region[reg, BaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[Directive@{Thick, Pink}]}, 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> True]
reg//Area
```

[image]

> `1`.

```
Clear[reg];
reg = ParametricRegion[{Cos[x^2 + Sin@y], 
    Cos[E^x - y]}, {{x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/2}}];
Region[reg, 
 BaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[3], Pink}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks too. I wonder why the edges seem to be a bit rough...

Comment: @youthdoo  `RegionPlot` automatic discrete the region, it is not easy to get the exact boundary.